# Attaching listeners to a new elements loaded after 1st page- Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, infinite-scroll

Bit new to Java-script so let me explain my problem. I have implemented pagination using `Django` and using `Infinitescroll.js` for pagination in Front-end.

Now I want to attach an click-event listener to elements of a class on the page. I can do.

```
$(".class").on("click", 
  function(){
  alert("1234")
});
```

**First page of Pagination is working fine**. But for next page the listener is not getting attached. I tried keeping above js in `$(document).ready` but still it's not working. How can I add listeners to new elements of the same class that are being loaded after pagination.
Do I need to put the above code in callback function of the `infinitescroll.js`?

Comment: There are hundreds of same questions in SO, but once again: use delegated event handlers. Something like `$(document).on("click", ".class", function() {` or with static parent selector instead of `document`

Comment: Mate thanks! Put it in answer I will accept it.

Comment: I read this concept somewhere but today I realised it's importance. Thanks again. Event Delegation.

Comment: You're welcome. It's actually not worth to be an answer. Furthermore, question is already marked as duplicate, so I wouldn't be able to post an answer even if I want to :) You can read about delegated events in [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).